# Disc or Square?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

I have the following notation: $$D= \{z\in C:|Re(z) |+|Im(z) |<1\}.$$ Would this be an open disc of radius $1$ or is it a (open i.e not including it's boundary) square with vertices at $\pm i$ and $\pm 1$?

Comment: Where does (the border of) $D$ intersect the $Re(z)=Im(z)$ diagonal?

Comment: At 0.5? If I've understood what you're asking

Comment: Yes. So? Square or disk?

Comment: So, it must be a square?

Comment: Yes, it is the square you mentioned.

Comment: Please do not delete posts for no apparent reason.

Comment: @Math301, would you like to accept the answer? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=x+iy$. It is given that $|x|+|y|<1$.

If $f=|x|+|y|-1$, then

$f=
\begin{cases}
x+y-1 & \;x>0, y>0\\
x-y-1 & \;x>0, y<0\\
-x+y-1 & \;x<0, y>0\\
-x-y-1 & \;x<0, y<0
\end{cases}$

This is how it looks

[image]